# Open a org-file with specified depth of headings

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The org file usually opens with level one of heading. Then I have to Strike C-u 2 S-tab to adjust them down to level 2 heading.

How could I specify the heading levels for various org files?

Answer (score 2):

`(org-content 2)` is your friend. You can add `eval: (org-content 2)` to a file's local variable settings to have it invoked automatically when you visit the file or you can `M-:` evaluate this any time.

Comment: How would you make this permanent (globally)? I had no success with ```(add-hook 'org-mode-hook '(org-content 2))```

Comment: The `add-hook` implies that you provide the name of a function: `(org-content 2)` is not suitable. However there is an easy workaround: just define a function `(defun my-org-depth () (org-content 2))` and then add `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-depth)`.

Comment: Thanks! Make sense.